# Sonar Issue : rename this abstract class

Tags: java, sonarqube, abstract-class, naming-conventions

There is simple minor issue reported in Sonar for an abstract class which says to update the class name as per regex: `'^Abstract|Base[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'`

It seems preety simple where we have to just append the word abstract in front of class name. But surprisngly, it is not solving the issue.

We are literally scratching our heads for this silly thing.
I even tried creating a new class to show the error below. Now, can anyone please guide me why sonar is still reporting this naming convention issue :
[image]

Comment: I strongly disagree with this rule - it doesn’t add anything to prefix every abstract class; just noise. Personally, I would disable this rule and move on to something productive.

Comment: To second @BoristheSpider's comment: it's as useful as prefixing interfaces with an `I`.

Comment: Depending on how Sonar matches (matching entire class name or not) the regex doesn't even mean what you said it means. Use a regex debugger to find out what the regex actually matches. That is probably why you are still getting the error even with the class name `AbstractClass`. Try with `public abstract class BaseJustTestingClass` and report if that one is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Existing rule checks that the class name is either `Abstract`, or has prefix `Base` followed by a capital letter and alphanumeric characters.

In order to check that the name of an abstract class should start with [`Abstract` or `Base` prefix](https://regex101.com/r/9yF61R/1), the regular expression in the rule should look like this: `^(Abstract|Base)[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`.

Thus, either the regexp in the rule should be fixed, or just disabled.